# How can I choose the features my q-learning with linear function approximation

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning, q-learning, function-approximation

I am developing AI using reinforcement-learning.

It is a game that player should avoid bricks falling from sky.

There are 20 bricks falling to the ground. 
[game screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jeTfb.png) , [game play video link](https://youtu.be/GtZQqjto74w)

I implemented AI using reinforcement-learning with linear function.

It was hard to choose the best features to get satisfied result.

Anyway it ended up getting best score ever since I tried to make it.

But It's quite weird.

There are some reasons.

1. It reached convergence very quickly around 10 training.
2. I just used 6 features.
3. I couldn't get better score through training more times. (Like I wanted my ai to play like super player. It didn't seem like it though.)

Meanwhile, I tried to use lots of features. I defined features as game screen size(960 * 640).

And I fill those features where brick's relative coordinates from player. I hoped that can make better result than previous one. I trained this method for 7 hours but It didn't work out.

The bottom line is How should I choose the features to make it work best or Is there any different approach to solve it?